# How to reset chunk size in ng-flow

Tags: angularjs, ng-flow

I am using ng-flow to upload images. I want to reset my chunk size .Is it possible from the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `forceChunkSize` parameter to `true`?

It would not reset the size, but it would force the same size for all uploads the entire time.

Comment: Actually i want to upload image upto 5mb as single chunk? Is it possible ?

Comment: Well you can set the chunk size to 5 Mb.

Comment: Is it possible from angular side?

Comment: Yes, see the samples how to set parameters: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/blob/master/samples/basic/app.js
One parameter is chunkSize. It should be 5 * 1024 * 1024.

Comment: @ Daniel Zolnai Thank you. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div flow-init="{query:{profile:profile,filedName: 'albums'},target: '/users/uploadPictures', testChunks:false,chunkSize:5*1024*1024}" flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()" flow-file-success="getProvider()">
```

set ***chunkSize*** to desired size